# Selenium: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using C# and Selenium Chromedriver to do a test project scraping Google Maps.

It works well until it gets to the second loop here:

```
var companyurl = company.GetAttribute("href");
```

Which returns back:

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Which I think is due to my list doing this, for some reason:
[image]

This is all my code:

```
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddExcludedArgument("excludeSwitches");
options.AddExcludedArgument("useAutomationExtension");
options.AddArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
options.AddArguments("enable-automation");
options.AddArguments("--log-level=OFF");
//options.AddArguments("headless");
options.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/lincoln+plumbers/");

try
{
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div > div > div.NIoIEf > div.G4njw > div.AIC7ge > form > div > div > button > span")).Click();
}
catch
{

}

IList<IWebElement> companies = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"pane\"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a"));

foreach (var company in companies)
{
    try
    {
        var companyurl = company.GetAttribute("href");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(companyurl);
        var companyName = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("h1")).Text;
        Console.WriteLine(companyName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: print `companyurl ` in that try block, I belive this should print the first one and for second iteration it is getting that exception ?

Comment: Changed to that and the exact same result @cruisepandey

Comment: Was there any output? I was expecting first company URL to be printed.

Comment: Yes, the first prints. Then the errors comes.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you call this:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(companyurl);
```

... you make "stale" all element references you have collected, including `companies`. I'd guess you want to redesign your algorithm to extract and save all the info you need from the 1st page, before you make its element references stale by navigating to other pages.